# manipulate jquery object from AJAX $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I would like to know how to manipulate the Data I'm getting as a return from a $.get Method call to a link.
Example:

```
$.get('/index.php?id='+before+'&type=110', function(data){
    var result = $(data).find('#ul1999 > *');
    console.log(result);
},'text');
```

The response of the Webpage would be similar to this:

```
<div>
    <ul id="ul1999">
        <li>
            <a href="#">something something</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">got a sub</a>
            <ul id="ul2014">
                 <li>
                      <a href="#" id="ta200">i'm the sub</a>
                 </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">something 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my returned value looks like this:

```
Object[li, li, li, li, li.last]
```

I now want to remove the parent element of id "ta200", so the entire li containing this id.
I tried to remove it with

```
var result = $(data).find('#ul1999 > *').not('#ta200').parent();
```

but it didn't work.

Maybe someone could tell me how to access the actual object and search for the id?

Comment: This question is perplexing, because your code does not give the result you suggest. Once you've corrected the HTML (the id should be `ul1999`, not `#ul1999`), it only gives the three top-level `li` elements, because you use the child selector `> *`.

Comment: Your answer actually made me rethink about the selector - changed it to `var result = $(data).find('#ul1999');$(result).find('#ta200').parent().remove();` and to cope with the parent I used the `$(result).children().unwrap();` so my resultlist is actually only the `<li>`'s without the unwanted one. Thank you for pointing this out @lonesomeday !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as this:

```
$(data).find("#ta200").parent().remove();
```

Here's a JSFiddle to better illustrate how you can manipulate an in-memory DOM like that and then retrieve the modified HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/xu6d3xhp/

Comment: This actually didn't work with my results given in the question. I think it was because it loaded only the `<li>` elements in the Object. When I changed my selector for the data result I was able to find the ID because every element was loaded into the Object.

Comment: Did you check the JSFiddle? It demonstrates that the indicated `<li>` was in fact removed from the `data`.